# Slickgrid frozenColumn doesnt work in example-column-group

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I want to freeze the first column in http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-column-group.html
for that i have added this in the options:
frozenColumn: 0

But it doesnt seem to work, instead the column group header disappears.

While debugging i see that $panelHeader is getting updated and yet i cannot see the Column header text
Let me know if anyone has come across this issue

Answer (score 0):

This issue is recently fixed, its available in the latest release.
Thanks to SlickGrid team!

Comment: https://github.com/6pac/6pac.github.io/blob/master/SlickGrid/examples/example-frozen-columns-and-column-group.html